# missing script: typings-install

Tags: typescript, angular, npm

I get the following error for the command: npm run typings-install:

```
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "typings-install"
npm ERR! node v6.2.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.9.5

npm ERR! missing script: typings-install
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\armyTik\Desktop\angular2_3\angular2-webpack-starter-master\angular2-webpack-starter\npm-debug.log
```

I have been trying install those: (but nothing solved the error)

```
npm run typings-install
typings install -g
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your `package.json` does not contain a `typings-install` script. Please include the `package.json` in your question to verify.

Also, `typings install -g` is not a valid command. You can run `typings install` if you have a `typings.json` file (next to the `package.json`). If you don't have any, you have to use install every dependency manually, like this:

```
typings i env~node@4 -SG  <-- this installs and saves the node v4 definitions
typings i dt~lodash -SG  <-- this installs and saves the lodash definitions from DefinitelyTyped
```

Also, if you need more help please give some details: what is this project, what are you planning to do, what is the content of your `package.json` and `typings.json` files, etc.

**UPDATE**

A couple of months passed by since my original answer. Now I'd recommend leaving `typings` at all and using `npm install @types/lodash --save` and similar instead. Read more here: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2016/06/15/the-future-of-declaration-files/

Answer (score 0):

You can use typescript 2.0 by installing with the command:

> npm install -g typescript@2.0

You can then install loadash with the command:

> npm install --save @types/lodash

Answer (score 0):

*npm run typings-install* is wrong command. Run *npm install* instead.